# Rich Text Filling space between two TextSpans

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

What I want to achieve:
The short text always be at the end of the long text, no matter how many lines it is.

[image]

Current Code:

```dart
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(
        text:
          'I am the way and the truth and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me.'),
      TextSpan(text: 'John'),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: cannot you use `CustomPainter` with `TextPainter`?

Comment: @pskink I haven't work with these two you mentioned.

Comment: check https://suragch.medium.com/how-to-paint-in-flutter-d18c6c26df10 for example

Comment: @pskink Thanks, I'll take a look at it